# How to query from JSON arrays from two different tables?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, multiple-tables

I have a table name `doc_definition` with a `json` column `definition` which has a format like:

```
[{
  "id":"0",
  "name:"Ques1"
 },{
  "id":"1",
  "name:"Ques2"
 },{
  "id":"2",
  "name:"Ques3"
}]
```

and another table `doc` which has another `json` column `def_val` with format as:

```
{
  "0":{
       "value":"Ans1"
      },
  "1":{
       "value":"Ans2"
      },
  "2":{
       "value":"Ans3"
      }
}
```

I want to create a Postgres SQL query that gives the value of a corresponding question by matching the id field inside both json.
SO far I've come up with this:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(def.definition) ->> 'name' AS json_test
FROM document_definitions AS def
INNER JOIN documents AS doc 
    ON doc.document_definition_id = def.id
WHERE doc.id = 892 AND json_array_elements(def.definition) ->> 'name' = 'Ques2'
```

But this throws exception:

```
ERROR:  argument of AND must not return a set
```

When i put the `json_array_elements(def.definition) ->> 'name' = 'Ques2'` in `SELECT` clause, it returns boolean value.

I dont know whats wrong then. Plz Help?

Comment: You have got to rethink it.... The definition of `json_arra_elements` is `Expands a JSON array to a set of JSON values.` ..That's why the first query fails. Further,. since in that set of value `Ques2` exists, the second query returns true... Read this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html  and try to rethink your approach

Comment: @JasonKrs I did rethink my approach and came up with a query that worked for me. I've posted it in the answers. Do let me know if there's anything i can improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and errors, I've come up with this.
Plz let me know if I can improve this in any way.

```
SELECT definition_json.definition_value -> definition_json.def_value_id ->> 'value' AS definition_value
FROM (
    SELECT json_array_elements(def.definition) ->> 'name' = 'Ques2' AS is_definition_present,
        json_array_elements(def.definition) ->> 'id' AS def_value_id,
        doc.definition_value, doc.id AS document_id, def.id AS definition_id
    FROM document_definitions AS def
    INNER JOIN documents AS doc 
        ON doc.document_definition_id = def.id
    ) AS definition_json
WHERE definition_json.is_definition_present = 't' AND definition_json.document_id = 892
```

Comment: As long as you your issue is resolved it's ok. If you ever get some performance issue, you'll think about tuning the query.  Don't forget to let me know if my answer help you in anyway or if at all accurate so that I can remove it to avoid misleading somebody else

Answer (score 0):

How about that query :

```
SELECT json_array_elements(def.definition) ->> 'name' AS json_test
FROM document_definitions AS def
INNER JOIN documents AS doc 
    ON doc.document_definition_id = def.id
WHERE doc.id = 892 AND (json_array_elements(def.definition) ::json->> 'name') = 'Ques2'
```